# Reversing the translation of the Pillow Image Library Rotation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, python-imaging-library, moviepy

I'm a bit of newbie at this,  trying to rotate an image in Python Pillow without changing the position of the centre of the rotated image.  OR by the pillow rotate looks of things... returning the centre back to it's original spin location.

In Pillow (Image.py) there is a function that rotates an image.  This function is as follows:-

```
def rotate(
        self,
        angle,
        resample=NEAREST,
        expand=0,
        center=None,
        translate=None,
        fillcolor=None,
    ):
        """
        Returns a rotated copy of this image.  This method returns a
        copy of this image, rotated the given number of degrees counter
        clockwise around its centre.
        :param angle: In degrees counter clockwise.
        :param resample: An optional resampling filter.  This can be
           one of :py:attr:`PIL.Image.NEAREST` (use nearest neighbour),
           :py:attr:`PIL.Image.BILINEAR` (linear interpolation in a 2x2
           environment), or :py:attr:`PIL.Image.BICUBIC`
           (cubic spline interpolation in a 4x4 environment).
           If omitted, or if the image has mode "1" or "P", it is
           set to :py:attr:`PIL.Image.NEAREST`. See :ref:`concept-filters`.
        :param expand: Optional expansion flag.  If true, expands the output
           image to make it large enough to hold the entire rotated image.
           If false or omitted, make the output image the same size as the
           input image.  Note that the expand flag assumes rotation around
           the center and no translation.
        :param center: Optional center of rotation (a 2-tuple).  Origin is
           the upper left corner.  Default is the center of the image.
        :param translate: An optional post-rotate translation (a 2-tuple).
        :param fillcolor: An optional color for area outside the rotated image.
        :returns: An :py:class:`~PIL.Image.Image` object.
        """

        angle = angle % 360.0

        # Fast paths regardless of filter, as long as we're not
        # translating or changing the center.
        if not (center or translate):
            if angle == 0:
                return self.copy()
            if angle == 180:
                return self.transpose(ROTATE_180)
            if angle == 90 and expand:
                return self.transpose(ROTATE_90)
            if angle == 270 and expand:
                return self.transpose(ROTATE_270)

        # Calculate the affine matrix.  Note that this is the reverse
        # transformation (from destination image to source) because we
        # want to interpolate the (discrete) destination pixel from
        # the local area around the (floating) source pixel.

        # The matrix we actually want (note that it operates from the right):
        # (1, 0, tx)   (1, 0, cx)   ( cos a, sin a, 0)   (1, 0, -cx)
        # (0, 1, ty) * (0, 1, cy) * (-sin a, cos a, 0) * (0, 1, -cy)
        # (0, 0,  1)   (0, 0,  1)   (     0,     0, 1)   (0, 0,   1)

        # The reverse matrix is thus:
        # (1, 0, cx)   ( cos -a, sin -a, 0)   (1, 0, -cx)   (1, 0, -tx)
        # (0, 1, cy) * (-sin -a, cos -a, 0) * (0, 1, -cy) * (0, 1, -ty)
        # (0, 0,  1)   (      0,      0, 1)   (0, 0,   1)   (0, 0,   1)

        # In any case, the final translation may be updated at the end to
        # compensate for the expand flag.

        w, h = self.size

        if translate is None:
            post_trans = (0, 0)
        else:
            post_trans = translate
        if center is None:
            # FIXME These should be rounded to ints?
            rotn_center = (w / 2.0, h / 2.0)
        else:
            rotn_center = center

        angle = -math.radians(angle)
        matrix = [
            round(math.cos(angle), 15),
            round(math.sin(angle), 15),
            0.0,
            round(-math.sin(angle), 15),
            round(math.cos(angle), 15),
            0.0,
        ]

        def transform(x, y, matrix):
            (a, b, c, d, e, f) = matrix
            return a * x + b * y + c, d * x + e * y + f

        matrix[2], matrix[5] = transform(
            -rotn_center[0] - post_trans[0], -rotn_center[1] - post_trans[1], matrix
        )
        matrix[2] += rotn_center[0]
        matrix[5] += rotn_center[1]

        if expand:
            # calculate output size
            xx = []
            yy = []
            for x, y in ((0, 0), (w, 0), (w, h), (0, h)):
                x, y = transform(x, y, matrix)
                xx.append(x)
                yy.append(y)
            nw = math.ceil(max(xx)) - math.floor(min(xx))
            nh = math.ceil(max(yy)) - math.floor(min(yy))

            # We multiply a translation matrix from the right.  Because of its
            # special form, this is the same as taking the image of the
            # translation vector as new translation vector.
            matrix[2], matrix[5] = transform(-(nw - w) / 2.0, -(nh - h) / 2.0, matrix)
            w, h = nw, nh

        return self.transform((w, h), AFFINE, matrix, resample, fillcolor=fillcolor)
```

This function also applies some translation (position shift) in order to keep the rotated images corners inside the image.  The part of the code that applies the translation is this line

```
matrix[2], matrix[5] = transform(-(nw - w) / 2.0, -(nh - h) / 2.0, matrix)
```

what I would like to do is extract the values of matrix[2] and matrix[5] so that I can reverse this translation, when the rotation is called in moviepy.

To achieve something like this...

```
import moviepy.editor as mped
image_clip = mped.ImageClip("image.jpg", duration=3)
rotated_image = image_clip.rotate(20).set_position((pillow_rotate_x.
                (-matrix[2]),pillow_rotate_y.(-matrix[5]))
```

So that it undoes the pillow translation, and returns the image centre to the place it was originally rotated at.

I was wondering how this could be achieved with the least code repetition ?

For example with the following code:-

```
import moviepy.editor as mped
import sys
import numpy as np

print("Python Version", sys.version)

baboon = mped.ImageClip("baboon.png", duration=3)
colour_clip = mped.ColorClip(size=[500, 50], color=np.array([250, 90, 0]).astype(np.uint8), duration=3) # important to use .astype(np.uint8)
cameraman = mped.ImageClip("cameraman.jpg", duration=3)
print("baboon_size", baboon.size)
print("colour_clip size", colour_clip.size)
print("cameraman size", cameraman.size)

rot_trans_col_clip = colour_clip.add_mask().rotate(20)
rot_trans_cameraman = cameraman.add_mask().rotate(20)
stacked_clips = mped.CompositeVideoClip([baboon, rot_trans_col_clip, rot_trans_cameraman])
stacked_clips.write_videofile('rotated_imagery_on_baboon.mp4', fps=5)
```

With the above code you can layer up some different types of content and rotate them.

The two input image files of the baboon and cameraman can be downloaded here:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17_s1IunwIAy1npJrsLRicieTG4NZYV4o/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G5YbApGX035-9mJtuz9GNgLr6jGywk-Z/view?usp=sharing

With the Translation code below (that is inside the pillow image.py file)

```
matrix[2], matrix[5] = transform(-(nw - w) / 2.0, -(nh - h) / 2.0, matrix)
```

the affect it has on the images is illustrated here:-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d_prYqb-fqizFcV0MD0rMXOIny2L0KW5/view?usp=sharing
You can see here that the centres of the two rotated images have been moved, so that their corners are still in view (not cropped).

Without the Pillow Translation code inside the pillow rotation function it looks like this:-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17POoZcuk9QAxJrnwD2LFsYd--SXdR9JA/view?usp=sharing

You can see here that although the corners are a bit cropped, the centres of the images have not moved.

This is the outcome that I want.  However, Pillow rotate applies a translation at the end.

Interestingly if you set expand=False on the pillow rotate:-

```
rot_trans_cameraman = cameraman.add_mask().rotate(20, unit='deg', expand=False)
```

you get this:-

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QEzJN3NlWK_sjxPLGC_BNs2xfxxfhAIH

which has the same centre points.  So it seems that without the expand flag set to false, the centre points move, however with it set to false, all the corners are cropped in symmetry.

The reason that this would be useful, is so that if you pass an angle to pillow rotate the outcome is deterministic, rather than also incorporating a translation that is dependent on the size of the images.

So my question is, how to restore the rotation centre locations ?

Comment: Can you post sample input and output images?

Comment: @Alderven I have edited the post to contain some code that does some rotation, and uploaded and shared two 3 second videos to illustrate the difference.  Do these help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is here:-

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4556

The new reference is after the expansion and centre reposition.  This can then be used in the global system to reposition the element.